# MySQL Performance Issue using Select, Count, and Group By

Tags: mysql, performance

I've been researching the best way to write this query, but I can't seem to get the performance to improve.

The query is used to build a "trending topics" tagcloud.

There are about a million records in the table and growing.

The InnoDB table structure is...

id - int(15) [AI, Primary, Unique]
topic - varchar(50)
datetime

And here is my query...

```
SELECT topic, COUNT(topic) AS topicCount 
FROM table 
WHERE datetime > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND topic!='' 
GROUP BY topic HAVING topicCount>1 
ORDER BY topicCount DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

The performance of the query is hovering around 300ms which is far too slow.

I added an index to topic, but the performance jumped to 1400ms.

Is there a more efficient way to write this query that would greatly improve performance?

Comment: You need an index on `datetime` as well

Comment: That vastly improved my performance - we're now seeing query times around 25ms. Fantastic!  Thank you!!  (If you throw that into an answer btw, I'll mark it as the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done indexing on topic but that will not improve the performance.

Add an index to `datetime` since you are doing range search and having index on that column will improve the performance.